# Query the <a> tag belonging to some parent

Tags: javascript, extjs

Say I have:

```
<div id = "someId">
  <a id="targetId"></a>
</div>
```

I want to get the id of the `<a>` tag, belonging to the div with `id="someId"`
How can I do this?

I tried:

```
document.getElementById("someId").tagName("a").id
```

And:

```
Ext.getCmp("someId").query("a").id;
```

Preferably i would want to do it in Extjs syntax, but in the end, pure JS will do too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeepbmrt/1/)**

There's many solutions, you can do it using `querySelector` for example :

```
document.querySelector("#someId a").id
```

Or also using `getElementsByTagName()` like this :

```
document.getElementById("someId").getElementsByTagName('a')[0].id
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get it by using ExtJS functions, then you could use the following code:

```
Ext.get('someId').query('a#targetId')[0].id)
```

Here is a fiddle for you; https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tef